# Cambiar imagen de Pins en Swift (MapView)

Tags: ios, swift, map

Tengo una App en donde mando a poner localizaciones con sus respectivos *Annotations*. Logré cambiar la imagen del pin, pero veo que todas las imágenes son cambiadas.

Lo que me gustaría hacer es mostrar una imagen diferente por cada grupo de localizaciones, por ejemplo, tengo hospitales y farmacias, entonces me gustaría poner una cruz roja en Hospital y una medicina en farmacia.

Por ahora solo tengo las cruces y he estado investigando pero sigo sin éxito. Espero me puedan ayudar.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "identifier")
    if annotationView == nil{
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "identifier")
        annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
        annotationView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)

        let pinImg = UIImage(named: "curz")
        let size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        pinImg!.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        annotationView!.image = resizedImage
    }
    else {
        annotationView!.annotation = annotation
    }
    return annotationView
}
```

Comment: En el código de ejemplo solo estás usando una imagen... ¿En qué casos usarías la otra?

Comment: Lo usaría para agregar el otro grupo de anotaciones (otra struct)

Comment: ¿Y cómo diferencias una _annotation_ de otra?

Comment: La verdad no tengo claro ese concepto, soy muy nuevo en Swift. Creo que sería por medio del "identifier"

Comment: ¿Cómo agregas las _annotations_ al mapa? ¿Ahí puedes diferenciarlas? Tal vez lo que te falte sea crear subclases de MKAnnotation para diferenciar de qué tipo es cada una, y así poder ponerle la imagen que le corresponda...

Comment: Ah, para añadirlas lo que hago es, tengo un Struct donde guardo los valores y coordenadas, después mediante un Loop (for struct in arreglo) donde el arreglo representa la información de cada una. Al final, verifica que si estan a menos de 10 KM del usuario las haga aparecer.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59514/discussion-between-marcos-crispino-and-daniel-c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer es tener una subclase de `MKAnnotation` donde guardes información que necesitas para poder saber de qué tipo se trata.

Algo así:

```
enum CustomAnnotationType {
    case hospital
    case farmacia
}

class CustomAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var type: CustomAnnotationType

    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, type: CustomAnnotationType) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.type = type
    }
}
```

Cuando agregas las *annotations* al mapa le dices de qué tipo se trata:

```
let customAnnotation = CustomAnnotation(coordinate: coord, type: .farmacia)
map.addAnnotation(customAnnotation)
```

y cuando vas a crear la vista para una *annotation* determinada, usas la imagen que corresponde para cada una:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }
    if let customAnnotation = annotation as? CustomAnnotation {
        let identifier = identifier(forCustomAnnotationType: customAnnotation.type)
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "identifier")
        if annotationView == nil{
            let imageName = imageName(forCustomAnnotationType: customAnnotation.type)
            ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Nota: `identifier(forCustomAnnotationType: )` e `imageName(forCustomAnnotationType: )` son funciones que deberías implementar con un `switch`...

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu ayuda y atención en mi caso :D